# certain cells are not copying over from one workbook to target workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy an entire row if there is a highlighted cell in that row from one workbook to another. I am now seeing that the values are being put into incorrect cells in the target workbook. I cannot find a trend on how the information is being placed. Some cells in the initial workbook may or may not be filled out, and that is fine, but I believe maybe that may be the issue since I am using End(xlUp). Any tips?

Basically, if a cell is highlighted, I want to copy that entire row into different columns of another workbook. Here is my code:

```
Sub Approval_Flow()
Dim AppFlowWkb As Workbook, ConfigWkb As Workbook
Dim AppFlowWkst As Worksheet, ConfigWkst As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, targetRng As Range


Set AppFlowWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\clara\Documents\Templates\FlowChangeLog.xlsx")
Set ConfigWkb = ThisWorkbook
Set AppFlowWkst = AppFlowWkb.Sheets("Editor")
Set ConfigWkst = ConfigWkb.Worksheets("Flows")


'looking through each column value before moving on to next row
For Each aCell In ConfigWkst.Range("A7:K" & ConfigWkst.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    'if cell is highlighted, copy that row's column D value
    If Not aCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
        'requesting office
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("D" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        'type
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("C" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        '1
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("E" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        '2
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("F" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        '3
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("G" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        '4
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("H" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        '5
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("I" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        '6
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("J" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        '7
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("K" & (aCell.Row)).Value
    End If
Next aCell
AppFlowWkst.Range("A:S").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code, cells from the same source rows may be scattered on different target rows. Also you're copying some source rows more than once (when a row has many highlighted cells). What you need is:

1- Get the target row *only once* and use it then increment it after each copy. That row should be the "last" non-empty row from the target sheet. You can make a loop to find that maximum, but a "lightweight" solution would be to use the first row after the `UsedRange`.

2- Also, you need to avoid copying the same source row multiple times. for this, you can keep track of the last copied source row during the iteration.

```
' get the first target row once before starting the transfer
Dim targetRow as Long, lastCopiedRow as long
targetRow = AppFlowWkst.UsedRange.row + AppFlowWkst.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each aCell In ConfigWkst.Range("A7:K" & ConfigWkst.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    If aCell.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255) And aCell.row > lastCopiedRow Then
        ' office                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("A" & targetRow) 
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("D" & (aCell.Row)).Value
        'type
        Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("B" & targetRow)
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("C" & (aCell.Row)).Value

        ' ... etc

        targetRow = targetRow + 1 ' <-- Increment the target row after each transfer
        lastCopiedRow = aCell.Row ' <-- also save this to avoid recopying the same row
    End If
Next aCell
```

Comment: Thank you. When I used this code, nothing was copied over to the target workbook. I am a bit confused why we are defining targetRow?

Comment: @gksdmsgP `targetRow` is the row you want to copy into. We need it so that different cells from the same source row wont be scattered on different rows in the destination. This is because you said that some cells may be empty.

Comment: That makes sense. However, nothing is being copied over to the destination. I used the step into function and see that the And aCell.row > lastCopiedRow doesn't allow for the rest of the row to enter the if-statement so I believe it is this:        
 Set targetRng = AppFlowWkst.Range("A" & targetRow) 
        targetRng.Value = ConfigWkst.Range("D" & (aCell.Row)).Value

Comment: @gksdmsgP that's puzzling. Would you examine the variables and check why the `If` condition is not met? what are the values of `aCell.Row` and `lastCopiedRow ` ??

Comment: I followed the aCell.Row  and lastCopiedRow and the targetRow started from cell 406. I fixed the code to accommodate mine. Thank you somuch!